# Ceiling Function Proof from First Principles?

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My question is whether it is possible to prove that a ceiling function exists ie.

If $a\in\mathbb R$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ satisfying $a\le n< a+1$.

The only solutions to this that I have found are those which involve floor/ceiling functions within the proof itself.

Where would one start in solving a proof like this? Possibly proof by contradiction?

Comment: This can be useful http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/06/30/prove-that-any-real-number-lies-between-exactly-one-pair-of-consecutive-integers/